# Scala Play Framework - Binding checkboxes with controllers

Tags: scala, checkbox, playframework

Can you give a simple example of binding checkboxes with controllers in play without using JS? I don't understand how should I transmit ids/names of checked checkboxes to controller...

Comment: What have you already tried by yourself?

Comment: `<input type="checkbox" name="@user._1.id" id="@user._1.id">`

I think checkbox should look something like this, but in that case what is the next step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to link between controller and the checkboxes is through the form:

So in controller if you have:

```
case class DemonstrateCheckBoxes (box1: Boolean, box2: Boolean)
```

and its related form:

```
val checkboxesForm = Form(
  mapping(
    "box1" -> boolean,
    "box2" -> boolean,
  )(DemonstrateCheckBoxes.apply)(DemonstrateCheckBoxes.unapply)
)
```

And then within the views you can use a form helper to write the following:

```
@(checkBoxesForm: Form[DemonstrateCheckBoxes])
@import helper._

<form action="/submitBoxes" method="POST"> 
  @checkbox(checkBoxesForm("box1"), '_label -> "Use box1?",'class -> "input-block-level",'placeholder -> "",'_help -> " ")
  @checkbox(checkBoxesForm("box2"), '_label -> "Use box2?",'class -> "input-block-level",'placeholder -> "", '_help -> " ")
  <button> Submit</button>
</form>
```

You can then later map the form within your controller as usual, to see it they 
are selected (value `true`) or not (value `false`).